# How to add multple plotlines for yaxis using highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

How to add multiple plotlines for yaxis using highcharts? I want the plotlines through out the charts. I know we can achieve this by adding value attribute but it is only for 1 value, i need it for entire yaxis

Comment: Please can you give an example of what you want? It's not very clear?!

Comment: Say using tickinternal 10, my charts gives yaxis labels as 10, 20, 30, 40 and 50 with plotlines but i want plotlines from 0 to 50 i.e, min to max

Comment: Can you give a jsFiddle illustrating the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're wanting `tickPositions` on the y-axis

```
    yAxis:{
        tickPositions:[1,10,20,30,40,50,200]   
    },
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/E95cr/1/
Docs: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickPositions

Answer (score 0):

Could you paste your mockup? You can set multiple plotLines, or use [plotbands](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.plotBands). If you would like to add line out of plotarea, you need to use [renderer](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer).